# How to prove that the set of all prime numbers is infinite?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What shall I do ?

-I tried to start with supposing to contrary that it's finite but I didn't reach anything .

-Also, I didn't find an injection from N to this set

Comment: Literally google your question and I'm sure you'll find multiple answers

Comment: There's about a billion ways to do this.

Comment: Euclid did this, only about say, 2300 years ago.

Comment: oh have you counted all the proofs?

Comment: see also herehttps://primes.utm.edu/notes/proofs/infinite/

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have only a finite set of primes. Take $x$ to be their product plus one. If non of the previous primes divides it you have constructed a new prime which is a contradiction. If not, there exist a prime $p$ which divides both $x$ and $x-1$. This means p divides 1 which is again a contradiction

Answer (score 0):

Since Allizdog has already provided Euclid's proof.

This comes from Euler.

Consider the zeta function:

$\zeta (s) = \sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty \frac {1}{n^s}$

$\zeta (s) = 1 + \frac {1}{2^s} + \frac {1}{3^s} + \cdots\\
\zeta (s) = \frac {1}{2^s} + \frac {1}{3^s} + \cdots\\
(\zeta (s) - \frac{1}{2^s} \zeta(s)) = 1 + \frac {1}{3^s} + \frac {1}{5^s} + \frac {1}{7^s} + \frac {1}{9^s}\cdots\\
\zeta(s)(1 - \frac{1}{2^s})(1-\frac{1}{3^s}) = 1 + \frac {1}{5^s} + \frac {1}{7^s} + \frac {1}{11^s}\cdots\\
\zeta(s) \prod_\limits {p \text{ prime }}(1-\frac {1}{p^s}) = 1\\
\zeta(s) = \prod_\limits {p \text{ prime }}(\frac {p^s}{p^s-1})\\
$

$\zeta(1) = \lim_\limits{k\to\infty}  \sum_\limits{n=1}^k \frac {1}{n} = \infty$

$\prod_\limits{p \text{ prime }}(\frac {p}{p-1}) = \infty$

If the number of prime numbers were finite this product would be finite.